# Tabs not showing up in envelope created from template

Tags: php, docusignapi

I'm trying to create a embedded envelope based on a template. The problem I am having is that in the created envelope the tabs I have created are missing.

I searched around and found the role assignment and used that and still no luck. When I look at the XML the role is the same as the template as well as the routing order and ID.

I tried setting the template so that I can't delete any recipients and I get the error:

Uncaught SoapFault exception: `[soap:Client] Required recipient in the template has not been provided. Recipient not satisfied for role, Signer, in template Test Form`

Here is my PHP to create and send the envelope, a lot of this is code used from the documentation:

```
// Get the recipient from a post
$rcp1 = new Recipient(); // First recipient to put in recipient array
$rcp1->UserName = $_POST['Name'];
$rcp1->Email = $_POST['Email'];
$rcp1->Type = RecipientTypeCode::Signer;
$rcp1->ID = "1";
$rcp1->RoutingOrder = 1;
$rcp1->CaptiveInfo = new RecipientCaptiveInfo();
$rcp1->CaptiveInfo->ClientUserId = 1;
$rcp1->RoleName = "Signer";
$rcp1->RequireIDLookup = FALSE;

// Create Role Assignments
$assign = new TemplateReferenceRoleAssignment();
$assign->RecipientID = $rcp1->ID;
$assign->RoleName = $rcp1->RoleName;

// Use a server-side template
$templateRef = new TemplateReference();
$templateRef->TemplateLocation = TemplateLocationCode::Server;
$templateRef->RoleAssignments = $assign;
$templateRef->Template = "****";



// Construct the envelope info
$envInfo = new EnvelopeInformation();
$envInfo->AccountId = $AccountID;
$envInfo->Subject = "This is the Subject";
$envInfo->EmailBlurb = "I have no Idea What a blurb is";



// Send creates draft with all the template info
$createEnvelopeFromTemplatesparams = new CreateEnvelopeFromTemplates();
$createEnvelopeFromTemplatesparams->TemplateReferences = array($templateRef);
$createEnvelopeFromTemplatesparams->Recipients = array($rcp1);
$createEnvelopeFromTemplatesparams->EnvelopeInformation = $envInfo;
$createEnvelopeFromTemplatesparams->ActivateEnvelope = true;
$env = $api->CreateEnvelopeFromTemplates($createEnvelopeFromTemplatesparams);
$envStatus = $env->CreateEnvelopeFromTemplatesResult;


// Construct the recipient token authentication assertion and specify
// ID, start time, method, and domain
$assertion = new RequestRecipientTokenAuthenticationAssertion();
$assertion->AssertionID = guid();
$assertion->AuthenticationInstant = nowXsdDate();
$assertion->AuthenticationMethod = RequestRecipientTokenAuthenticationAssertionAuthenticationMethod::Password;
$assertion->SecurityDomain = "Request Recipient Token Test";



// Construct the URLs based on UserName
$recip = $envStatus->RecipientStatuses->RecipientStatus[0];
$urls = new RequestRecipientTokenClientURLs();
$urlbase = getCallbackURL('pop.php');
$urls->OnSigningComplete = $urlbase . "?event=SignComplete&uname=" . $recip->UserName;
$urls->OnViewingComplete = $urlbase . "?event=ViewComplete&uname=" . $recip->UserName;
$urls->OnCancel = $urlbase . "?event=Cancel&uname=" . $recip->UserName;
$urls->OnDecline = $urlbase . "?event=Decline&uname=" . $recip->UserName;
$urls->OnSessionTimeout = $urlbase . "?event=Timeout&uname=" . $recip->UserName;
$urls->OnTTLExpired = $urlbase . "?event=TTLExpired&uname=" . $recip->UserName;
$urls->OnIdCheckFailed = $urlbase . "?event=IDCheck&uname=" . $recip->UserName;
$urls->OnAccessCodeFailed = $urlbase . "?event=AccesssCode&uname=" . $recip->UserName;
$urls->OnException = $urlbase . "?event=Exception&uname=" . $recip->UserName;


// Send
$requestRecipientTokenparams = new RequestRecipientToken();
$requestRecipientTokenparams->EnvelopeID = $envStatus->EnvelopeID;
$requestRecipientTokenparams->ClientUserID = $recip->ClientUserId;
$requestRecipientTokenparams->Username = $recip->UserName;
$requestRecipientTokenparams->Email = $recip->Email;
$requestRecipientTokenparams->AuthenticationAssertion = $assertion;
$requestRecipientTokenparams->ClientURLs = $urls;
$response = $api->RequestRecipientToken($requestRecipientTokenparams);
$tokenUrl = $response->RequestRecipientTokenResult;


echo '<iframe src="' . $tokenUrl . '" width="100%" height="720px"></iframe>';
```

This is the recipient info that is returned when I `RequestTemplate()`:

```
[0] => Recipient Object
                                (
                                    [ID] => 1
                                    [UserName] => 
                                    [SignerName] => 
                                    [Email] => 
                                    [Type] => Signer
                                    [AccessCode] => 
                                    [AddAccessCodeToEmail] => 
                                    [RequireIDLookup] => 
                                    [IDCheckConfigurationName] => 
                                    [PhoneAuthentication] => 
                                    [SignatureInfo] => 
                                    [CaptiveInfo] => 
                                    [CustomFields] => 
                                    [RoutingOrder] => 1
                                    [IDCheckInformationInput] => 
                                    [AutoNavigation] => 
                                    [RecipientAttachment] => 
                                    [Note] => 
                                    [RoleName] => Signer
                                    [TemplateLocked] => 
                                    [TemplateRequired] => 1
                                    [TemplateAccessCodeRequired] => 
                                    [DefaultRecipient] => 
                                    [SignInEachLocation] => 
                                )
```

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong, just to double-check are you positive that the role name on the template you're referencing is set to `Signer` ?  Since you're setting `$rcp1->RoleName = "Signer";` then the role name saved in the template needs to match exactly.

Comment: Added my recipient info taken straight from the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be due to you instatiating the templateRoleAssignments as an object and not an array.  Since you're using the SOAP api and not REST have you seen the DocuSign SOAP SDK up on Github?  That has sample code and projects for 5 different environments including PHP (`PHP`, `Java`, `C#`, `Ruby`, and `Salesforce`):

**https://github.com/docusign/DocuSign-eSignature-SDK**

Looking at a function defined in the PHP project I see the following:

```
function createFinalRoleAssignments($recipients) {
    $roleAssignments[] = new TemplateReferenceRoleAssignment();

    foreach ($recipients as $r) {
        $assign = new TemplateReferenceRoleAssignment();
        $assign->RecipientID = $r->ID;
        $assign->RoleName = $r->RoleName;
        array_push($roleAssignments, $assign);
    }

    // eliminate 0th element
    array_shift($roleAssignments);

    return $roleAssignments;
}
```

Notice how `$roleAssignments` is declared as an array using square brackets `[]`, I have a strong feeling that is causing your error.  Try defining your roleAssignments the same way and that will probably work.

Comment: Thanks! That did it. I looked at the sample files originally and thought because I only was worried about one recipient that I didn't need the array.

Comment: Cool, anyway you can accept and upvote my answer? :)  Thx, -Ergin